# Error when set multi style properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
document.getElementById('style').style.color = "FFFF00";
document.getElementById('style').style.fontWeight = "bold";
document.getElementById('style').style.font= "italic bold 20px arial,serif";
</script>
```

Whenusing multi css, the code has an error. How to fix it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You could have defined the values in a class and do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("error_width").className = "your_class_name";
```

Hope it helps